# How much traffic is high-traffic

Tags: website, traffic

My primary interest is in gathering information about the technology used behind public facing websites.  Much of the information I read arbitrarily differentiates between high-traffic vs the unstated *non-high-traffic* websites.  This troubles me because I don't have a good grasp of how much traffic is high-traffic.

Can anyone help me with this, is there a good rule of thumb?

Please don't tell me it depends ;)

Comment: Well, it does depend... it depends on who's writing the document you're reading.  You really have to ask them what they mean by high vs. "non-high" traffic.  There is no technical definition of this term--and the meaning of the term is likely to change over time.

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you gave a specific reason for closing the question.  I find it arrogant.

Comment: I didn't vote to close your question, but the reason is given in the closed notice: "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form."  I think my comment above, and the three answers give plenty of other clues as well: Your question is essentially un-answerable.  It's far too subjective, vague, and broad. I don't think it's arrogant at all. Perhaps you could re-ask, with a SPECIFIC question.

Comment: @Flimzy: My previous comment was not directed at you, but at those who closed it.  I appreciate the comment you previously wrote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`It Depends`
No, seriously - there is no straight cut-and-dry answer for this question.

Constantly transferring multiple gigabytes every minute? That's high-traffic.

Constantly handling several million requests per second? That's high-traffic.

A perfume retailer's site that gets one request a day... except the week before Mother's Day and St. Valentine's Day? That's high-traffic, even if the average over the year is decidedly low-traffic.

---

The best definition I can give you is that "High Traffic" is the point at which:

1. You start to worry about bandwidth limitations
2. You start to worry about your infrastructure (hardware/software/network) keeping up with the load.
3. You know that an outage will cause enough noise that it will be a problem (customers notice and complain)
   (this one is also the beginning of the definition for "Business Critical"…)

Comment: @vorataq7: Thank you for answering, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy, somebody is using fancy words.

Your question has more buzz words then the actual context, and yes it depends what you are serving.

High traffic for a file hosting site might be measured in outgoing bandwidth, high traffic for a regular web site might be measured in requests/p seconds, etc.

Comment: Seriously, I cannot find a single buzz word in my question.  I'm convinced you're confusing two questions, mine and another.

Answer (score 0):

Quantcast keeps track of the traffic received by a large fraction of the sites on the internet. The [top 100 sites](http://www.quantcast.com/top-sites) listing should give you a good ballpark estimate of the amount of traffic that these sites receive.

*Note*: in the interest of full disclosure, I work for Quantcast, but this particular resource is relevant to this question.